# Reading strings from file separated by space in Fortran

Tags: string, file-io, fortran, format

I am reading large files in Fortran that contain mixed string/numeric data such as:

```
114 MIDSIDE 0 0 O0002        436        437        584        438
115 SURFACE M00002 0 0        359        561        560        356
412236 SOLID   M00002 O00001 0      86157      82419      82418      79009
```

Currently, each line is read as a string and then post-processed to identify the proper terms. I was wondering if there is any way to read each line as an integer followed by four strings **separated by space**, and then some more integers; i.e. similar to '(I10,4(A6,X),4I10)' format, but without any information on the size of each string.

Does not work (charr is empty, iarr(2:5)=0):

```
INTEGER IARR(5)
CHARACTER*30 CHARR(4)
C open the file with ID=1
READ(1,*)IARR(1),(CHARR(I),I=1,4),(IARR(I),I=2,5)
```

Works (only for the last line in the data example):

```
INTEGER IARR(5)
CHARACTER*30 CHARR(4)
C open the file with ID=1
READ(1,'(I10,4(A7,X),4I10)')IARR(1),(CHARR(I),I=1,4),(IARR(I),I=2,5)
```

The issue is I don't know a-priori what would be the size of each string.

Comment: I actually tried that as the first attempt, but I got error in reading. Only the first integer is read, with other integers being zero and the strings being blank.

Comment: I found that for list-directed input, the string cannot contain separators or whitespace (spaces or tabs). This is probably why I cannot read them using READ(1,*)IARR(1),(CHARR(I),I=1,4),(IARR(I),I=2,5), but I can read it using something similar to READ(1,'(I10,4(A6,X),4I10)')IARR(1),(CHARR(I),I=1,4),(IARR(I),I=2,5). However, the problem is the characters are not of the same pre-known length. The list-directed format seems to read as much as the character length.

Comment: There is a bit of a problem in that with the input file given, the 'Does not work' example should work and the 'Works' example should not work. It seems that you already know how to parse the file but want to achieve your goal without the intermediate variable containing the line of input. Perhaps if you posted the code that parses the intermediate variable it might be possible.

Comment: You are right. I actually found out there is no problem in Fortran 90, and the f77rtl flag has been used in building the code which is causing this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found out the f77rtl flag was used to compile the project, and when I removed the flag, the issue was resolved. So the list-directed input format works just fine.

Comment: Glad you fixed it but f77rtl *shouldn't* do anything here.